# IPython autoreload doesn't work with Module level __init__.py

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, ipython-magic

Let's assume we have the following package structure.

```
module
 __init__.py
 +--> submodule
      __init__.py
      +--> subsubmodule
      __init__.py
      importantstuff.py
```

Classes from `importantstuff` can be imported by writing `from module.submodule.subsubmodule.importantstuff import ImportantClass`.

If I put that line in the module level `__init__.py` then importing can be shorten to `from module import ImportantClass`.

Now, if I use that shortcut in combination Autoreload IPython Magic commands:

```
In [1]: %load_ext autoreload

In [2]: %autoreload 2
```

Changes in the class `ImportantClass` will no longer automatically picked up.

Is there a workaround?